# Javascript/for loop/HTML table positioning

Tags: javascript

Description of program:
-My program uses a javascript for loop to place the data from an external javascript array named "arrays.js" into an HTML table. This program is suposed to place the correct data under  the "Date Name Address Amount" table headings.

Problem:
-The data in the array is overstepping its boundarys or I should say lack of boundaries set within the table headers "Date Name Address Amount" Its not creating a new record after the "Amount" header, its simply adding the new record to the same line.I would like it to wrap back around to the next record row starting under "Date" table header. so that the dates value in the arrya will be under the "date" header, name value under the "Name" header...etc example bellow....
Example: I have 4 headers (Date, Name, Address, Amount) I would like the start of the next date under the next array to be placed under the "Date" table header.It placing the next date value of the array on the same row its not wraping around to a new record row. Code is bellow.
Date         Name           Address     Amount

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Winch - Lab 10</title>
        <script src="arrays.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function totalContributions()
            {
                var totalAmount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < amount.length; i++)
                    totalAmount = totalAmount + amount[i];
                return totalAmount;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table id="donations">
         <tr>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Address</th>
             <th>Amount</th>
         </tr>
         <script>
             for (var x=0; x < amount.length; x++){
                 if (x%2==0){
                    document.write("<tr>");
                 } else {
                     document.write("<tr class='stripe'>");
                 }
                  document.write("<td>"+date[x]+"</td>");
                  document.write("<td>"+firstName[x]+" "+lastName[x]+"</td>");
                  document.write("<td>"+street[x]+"<br>"+city[x]+","+state[x]+" "+zip[x]);
                  document.write("<td class='amt'>$"+amount[x]+"</td>");
                  document.write("</tr)");
             }

         </script>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>

**arrays.js**

street = new Array();
city = new Array();
state= new Array();
zip = new Array();
amount = new Array();
date = new Array();


firstName[0]="Ron";
lastName[0]="Burgundy";
street[0]="88 Regal Lane";
city[0]="Williamsburg";
state[0]="KY";
zip[0]="40769";
amount[0]=625;
date[0]="2015-07-18";


firstName[1]="Ricky";
lastName[1]="Bobby";
street[1]="407 Easy Street";
city[1]="London";
state[1]="KY";
zip[1]="40744";
amount[1]=75;
date[1]="2015-07-18";


firstName[2]="Veronica";
lastName[2]="Corningstone";
street[2]="743 Stawlings Drive";
city[2]="Danville";
state[2]="KY";
zip[2]="40423";
amount[2]=50;
date[2]="2015-07-16";


firstName[3]="Brick";
lastName[3]="Tamland";
street[3]="102 Maple Lane";
city[3]="Danville";
state[3]="KY";
zip[3]="40423";
amount[3]=150;
date[3]="2015-07-15";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You forgot to define `firstName` and `lastName` variables in arrays.js file.
2) Inside for-loop the `tr` tag is not closed, changed `document.write("</tr)");` to `document.write("</tr>");`.

Working Code:

Html Code:

` 
    
    
        
        Winch - Lab 10
        
        
            function totalContributions()
            {
                var totalAmount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < amount.length; i++)
                    totalAmount = totalAmount + amount[i];
                return totalAmount;
            }

```
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="donations" style="width:100%;" border="1">
     <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Amount</th>
     </tr>
     <script>
         for (var x=0; x < amount.length; x++){
             if (x%2==0){
                document.write("<tr>");
             } else {
                 document.write("<tr class='stripe'>");
             }
              document.write("<td>"+date[x]+"</td>");
              document.write("<td>"+firstName[x]+" "+lastName[x]+"</td>");
              document.write("<td>"+street[x]+"<br>"+city[x]+","+state[x]+" "+zip[x]);
              document.write("<td class='amt'>$"+amount[x]+"</td>");
              document.write("</tr>");
         }

     </script>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

arrays.js

```
street = new Array();
city = new Array();
state= new Array();
zip = new Array();
amount = new Array();
date = new Array();
firstName = new Array();
lastName = new Array();

firstName[0]="Ron";
lastName[0]="Burgundy";
street[0]="88 Regal Lane";
city[0]="Williamsburg";
state[0]="KY";
zip[0]="40769";
amount[0]=625;
date[0]="2015-07-18";

firstName[1]="Ricky";
lastName[1]="Bobby";
street[1]="407 Easy Street";
city[1]="London";
state[1]="KY";
zip[1]="40744";
amount[1]=75;
date[1]="2015-07-18";

firstName[2]="Veronica";
lastName[2]="Corningstone";
street[2]="743 Stawlings Drive";
city[2]="Danville";
state[2]="KY";
zip[2]="40423";
amount[2]=50;
date[2]="2015-07-16";

firstName[3]="Brick";
lastName[3]="Tamland";
street[3]="102 Maple Lane";
city[3]="Danville";
state[3]="KY";
zip[3]="40423";
amount[3]=150;
date[3]="2015-07-15";
```

Comment: changed document.write("</tr)"); to document.write("</tr>");  **Code works now, Im new to stackoverflow tried to up vote the answer but I don't have enof points to do so? I will come back and do so when I receive more points. Thanks "Core" I will come back to reward you.

Comment: @EdwardWinch No problem, I am glad it helped you :).

Answer (score 0):

The world is moving to Angular, and I would recommend you to do same.

In Angular way, you can do this using either the angular-data-table or using the angular-material-data-table.

- angular-data-table works fine with 1.5.8 but will not be supported in
  angular2
- angular material-data-table (md-data-table) works with 1.5.8
  and will be supported in angular2 too.

Below is an example of md-data-table

> ```
>  <mdt-table table-card="{visible: true, title: 'Donations'}" paginated-rows = "true">
>     <mdt-header-row>
>       <mdt-column align-rule="left"><b>Name</b></mdt-column>
>       <mdt-column align-rule="left"><b>Description</b></mdt-column>
>       <mdt-column align-rule="left"><b>Since Year</b></mdt-column>
>     </mdt-header-row>
>     <mdt-row ng-repeat="item in donations">
>       <mdt-cell>{{item.name}}</mdt-cell>
>       <mdt-cell>{{item.description}}</mdt-cell>
>       <mdt-cell>{{item.since_yr}}</mdt-cell>
>     </mdt-row>
>   </mdt-table>
> ```

- The above code also does pagination for you. Awesome!
- The above code can also be used to make rows selectable by putting in :

  selectable-rows="true"  in

What u have to do is:-

> write a angular module using ng-app and that can be included in ur body tag or create a parent tag on top of above code.
>   write a controller to move ur logic into the controller. 
>   Below is an example.

```
angular.module('testModule',[])
        .controller('testController', function($scope){
            $scope.donations = function (){
                //Your logic for donations goes here.
            };      
        });
```